# copy data from another file in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two data from two different file, first file is from SHU.xls like this, data in C8:C1484

```
id
=========
198610030
199210037
199210038
199410020
199410042
```

and from ikprmeidet13.xls, data in B2:B1040

```
id          name
===================
200210046   MARINA
200110026   ERRIE
200110031   KANAE
200210061   SHIINA
```

I want to copy data (id and name) from ikprmeidet13.xls that doesn't exist in SHU.xls, I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
=IF((VLOOKUP([ikprmeidet13.xls]ikprmeidet13!$B$2:$B$1040;$C$8:$C$1484;1;FALSE)<>$C$8:$C$1484);[ikprmeidet13.xls]ikprmeidet13!$B$2:$B$1040;"")
```

I put that function in cell A1489 in SHU.xls, when I tried to evaluate formula, vlookup got an error, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Append a copy of one list to a copy of the other then identify and remove duplicates to suit. Say use:

> =VLOOKUP(C1485,C$1:C$1484,1,FALSE)

to identify `id` matches (display `id`) or not (display `#N/A`), filter to select rows containing the formula showing an `id` and then delete them.